# Is it possible to write flowfile selectively to tcp connections in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm writing a tcp server which sit between customers and workers. Both customer and worker will connect to the server by tcp connection and the connection should keep open.

When worker connect to my server, I'll keep them in a pool of available workers. when customer connects and send request to my server, the server will do some processing and relay the request to one of the worker in the pool.

Can nifi achieve the above? From the listentcp and puttcp processors, it seems it's impossible to choose from tcp connections.

Answer (score 1):

ListenTCP is a server and PutTCP is a client.

There is no way to have two different types of connections made to a single ListenTCP and then have those connections communicate with each other.

You could have ListenTCP receiving connections from customers and then send the data to the works using PutTCP, assuming the workers had their own TCP server. I don't know what your workers are doing, but you could also eliminate the workers and implement their logic in NiFi so you just have customers -> ListenTCP -> rest of the logic in the flow.